# Is there any way to contain text in a rectangle?

Tags: swiftui

Width and height of the `rectangle` has been set. I want to contain the text inside it and if text is longer than the space which `rectangle` can fit, it should `truncate`.
How to `contain or nest` the `text` inside the `rectangle`? is applying `padding` to the `text` only way to do it or is there any other proper way?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
                 
    
            ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous)
   
                    .stroke(Color.black , lineWidth: 1)
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 100, alignment: Alignment.top   )
        
                Text("loonngg textttttt tt DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD")
     
        }
            }
        }
 
 

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `Text` as an overlay of the `Rectangle`

```swift
var body: some View {
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous)
        .stroke(Color.black , lineWidth: 1)
        .frame(width: 300, height: 100, alignment: Alignment.top   )
        .overlay(Text("loonngg textttttt tt DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD"))
}
```

You can even set it as `background` instead of `overlay`.

Or if you want to keep same structure you did with `ZStack`, you can set the `layoutProiority` on the rectangle.

```swift
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous)
            .stroke(Color.black , lineWidth: 1)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 100, alignment: Alignment.top   )
            .layoutPriority(1) // default is 0, now this has higher priority than text
        Text("loonngg textttttt tt DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD")
    }
}
```